# Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 still exists after trying out all the solutions

Tags: android

I have added an external jar file to my application.
When I remove my jar file the error disappears. But I require the jar file in my application.
I have also done clean -> build  but the error still exists.

I initially added my jar file as app-> right click properties -> build path -> libraries -> add external jar.

Since that too generated the same error I directly copy pasted my jar file in libs of my application.
i.e in Android private libs -> native libs

Please can someone suggest what should I do to use the jar file and remove the error.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add it as a Library under Project Property/Java Build Path?